There is no record of image input in the vue project, but an error comes out


View page sources after running


<script defer src="/js/chunk-vendors.js"></script>
<script defer src="/js/app.js"></script>
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/img/icons/favicon.svg">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/./img/icons/favicon-192x192.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/./img/icons/favicon-192x192.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#3F6AD8">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="TestApp">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/./img/icons/favicon-192x192.png">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/./img/icons/favicon-192x192.png" color="#3F6AD8">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/./img/icons/favicon-192x192.png">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#000000">



I don't understand why it's above. I don't remember writing that code


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.png"> <!-- 아이콘 경로 수정 -->
  <title>testTitle</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <noscript>
    <strong>We're sorry but doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
  </noscript>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <!-- 이 부분에 실제 앱이 마운트 됩니다 -->
</body>
</html>



I don't remember writing anything other than this sauce.

I don't know why that error is coming out... I want to get rid of it, but if anyone knows how to do it, please let me know
I keep asking questions with gpt, I Google and try, but I still can't solve it, so I'm going to ask you one last question
Maybe there's a problem with the sauce underneath.. I want you to tell me how to fix it so that I don't find the svg.


vue.config.js

const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  runtimeCompiler: true,
  productionSourceMap: false,
  publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL || "/",
  lintOnSave: false,
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.symlinks(false);
  },
  devServer: {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 8880,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV), // 변경 사항: process.env 전체를 덮어쓰지 않고, 구체적인 필드만 설정
        "process.browser": JSON.stringify(true), // 변경 사항: 값을 명확히 JSON.stringify를 사용하여 정의
        __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: JSON.stringify(true),
        __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: JSON.stringify(false),
        __VUE_PROD_HYDRATION_MISMATCH_DETAILS__: JSON.stringify(true),
      }),
    ],
  },
  pwa: {
    iconPaths: {
      favicon16: "./img/icons/favicon-192x192.png",
      favicon32: "./img/icons/favicon-192x192.png",
      appleTouchIcon: "./img/icons/favicon-192x192.png",
      maskIcon: "./img/icons/favicon-192x192.png",
      msTileImage: "./img/icons/favicon-192x192.png",
    },
    name: "TestApp",
    themeColor: "#3F6AD8",
    icons: [
      {
        src: "./img/icons/favicon-192x192.png",
        sizes: "192x192",
        type: "image/png",
        purpose: "any maskable",
      },
      // 추가 아이콘 정의
    ],
    msTileColor: "#000000",
    appleMobileWebAppCapable: "yes",
    appleMobileWebAppStatusBarStyle: "black",
    workboxPluginMode: "GenerateSW",
  },
};



There was some information missing, so I corrected it.

i think you try using relative path instead of directive path

There was some information missing, so I corrected it.

The error is self-explanatory, do you have a favicon? If yes, then your path is not correct (edit your Webpack configuration). If not, then add one. Oh and you can also drop asking any questions to GPT, not gonna help you.
